# Issue while updating Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-mongodb

In my current project I need to update the Spring Data MongoDB framework to the latest (3.4.1) version because of CVE-2022-22980 vulnerability. The project contains parent and child sub-projects. The Spring Boot version is `2.1.1`. In parent `pom.xml` I have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.boot.version}</version> <!-- 2.1.1 -->
   <type>pom</type>
   <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Spring Data MongoDB dependency is placed in child `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But in dependency tree for some reasons I see the old version of `spring-data-mongodb ver.2.1.3`
[image]

I have no idea why maven don't update the version correctly. I tried exclude `spring-data-mongodb` from `spring-boot-dependencies` in parent's `pom.xml`, but unsuccessfully.

Any ideas what can be the reason of incorrect version updating by maven? I tried clear the cache of Intellij, cleared everything from `.m2` folder, but couldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  ChatGPT-4 is no help either.  Did you ever find a solution?